May deterministic computations produce different results when run on computers with different CPUs of the same architecture?
I'm trying to pinpoint the source of inconsistency in the results of a long computation across different hardware. Some computers produce result A, and others produce result B.
Assuming all other environment details (other hardware, Linux kernel version, glibc version, compiler settings, etc.) are the same, is it possible that computers with different CPUs of the same architecture (x86_64 in my case) produce different results for the same deterministic computation?

This question seems related, but I'm not sure that its answers answer the question above.

Does "determistic" mean no use of a RNG (random number generator) at all, or does it include a RNG with a determined seed? Also, is it exactly the same executable on the different machines, or do you compile it for each machine?

Also, how much do the results differ?

This question is similar to: How to achieve fortran numerical results reproducibility across different platforms (Intel vs AMD)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Related: Is SSE floating-point arithmetic reproducible? (yes, it's fully specified, the same machine code is required to produce the same results on every CPU except for fast-approximation instructions like rsqrtps) / Does any floating point-intensive code produce bit-exact results in any x86-based architecture?

If we assume all other environment details to be the same, (which is practically never the case, and I would strongly recommend looking for the difference there,) then this could still happen due to a number of possible reasons.

A hardware bug. An example this would be the Pentium FDIV bug (Wikipedia).

A CPU model-dependent software bug. An example of that would be some faulty SIMD (Wikipedia) code that only gets executed if a SIMD-capable CPU is detected, whereas some traditional, slower, but properly working code gets executed if a SIMD-capable CPU is not detected.


Furthermore, the observed differences could be due to some rarely considered "environment details" that will always cause different behavior between different computers:

Different absolute time coordinates. The current absolute time coordinate will never be exactly the same between two computers, and as a result nothing that depends on time will be the same. An important example of something which depends on time is pseudo-random number generation, which some people think is deterministic, but it is not, when seeded with the current time coordinate.

Race conditions caused by faulty multi-threading code. (Another form of software bug.)  A race condition will never be experienced the same way in two computers, even if they are identical in all respects.

Different clock speeds between different CPU models of the same architecture. (Of course, if the clock speed can affect the results of an algorithm which was intended to be deterministic, then this is essentially a software bug.)

Spread-Spectrum Clocking (Wikipedia) interfering with timekeeping algorithms (theoretically).



Regarding SIMD vs no SIMD, there can be differences on floating point calculations even without any bug, just because the operations are not performed in the same order.

@PierU I did not know that, thanks.

The primary example of what @PierU is talking about is code like a dot-product or summing an array where SIMD is only usable at all if you pretend that FP math is associative so you can group your additions differently.  It's not, you get different rounding errors, that's why compilers can only auto-vectorize foo += arr[i] for floating point with -ffast-math or #pragma omp simd reduction (+:foo) to tell the compiler to optimize as if FP math were associative.

This isn't normally considered "faulty" or a bug (in fact usually has better rounding error than naive sum += arr[i] since it's a step in the direction of pairwise summation: Simd matmul program gives different numerical results), but runtime dispatch to functions with different rounding error isn't something you can do if you need deterministic FP.

Your "different precision" bullet point is unrelated to what comments are discussing.  On x86-64 that's only possible for code that uses legacy x87 fsin or other fancy instructions whose results aren't exactly specified.  Is SSE floating-point arithmetic reproducible? - yes, the result of addss or addsd is fully specified.  Even basic x87 instructions like fadd give the same result on every CPU as long as the x87 precision-control bits are set the same way, which should be the case when running the same executable.  (Unless a different library ve

@PeterCordes I agree, I already removed it.
